# ожидание сокета

Tags: javascript, java, многопоточность, wildfly

У меня есть приложение на JSF+Primefaces в котором реализован механизм авторизации. По средствам servlet.Filter я просматриваю все входящие запросы и редиректю на страницу авторизации, если авторизации небыло (и на 404 страницу, если запрос на несуществующую страницу).

Все работает. Захотелось сделать так, что бы в случае выхода пользователя (logout) с одной из страниц другие открытые страницы так же автоматически вышли. Теоретически можно сделать регулярно повторяющийся на сервер запрос, но такой подход кажется мне не корректным (постоянный трафик от пользователей и не мгновенный выход).

Я решил реализовать COMET архитектуру, для этого на страницах при загрузке я открываю js сокет и делаю запрос на сервер.

JS:

```
  function loginControl() {
                 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                 xhr.open('GET', 'myURL/'+uuidv4(),true);
                 xhr.send("");
                 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                     if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                         if (xhr.status === 200) {
                             if (xhr.response == 'logout') {
                                 window.location.replace('login.xhtml');
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
             function uuidv4() {
                 return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
                     var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r &amp; 0x3 | 0x8);
                     return v.toString(16);
                 });
             }
```

(uuidv4 - Это эксперименты, что бы при каждом новом запросе был новый URL, думал решит проблему "ожидание сокета").

```
public class SecurityFilterr implements Filter  {

    @Inject
    private Access access;

 @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException { 
//...
if((resource != null) && (resource.length()> 6) && (resource.substring(0,6).equals("myURL/"))) {
            try {
                PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
                AccessEntity ae = new AccessEntity();
                access.addToListPage(ae);
                ae.logoutControl(false);
                printWriter.write("logout");
                printWriter.close();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex ){
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
            return;
        }
//...
}
}
```

AccessEntity - класс где я "засыпаю" поток

```
public class AccessEntity {
    synchronized public void logoutControl(boolean logout) throws InterruptedException {
        if(logout){
            this.notifyAll();
        } else {
            this.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Access

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Access implements Serializable {

    private List<AccessEntity> listPage;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        //..
        listPage = new ArrayList();
    }

public String logout()  {

//..
        try {
            for (AccessEntity obj : listPage){
                obj.logoutControl(true);
            }
            listPage = new ArrayList<>();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        return "logout";
    }

}
```

Основная суть - делаю через js запрос на сервер, а сервер сразу не отвечает, а засыпает. Возвращает ответ он только когда произошел logout. После ответа js редиректит на страницу авторизации.

Когда открыто 2-3 страницы все отрабатывает, но когда открыто 6-7 7-я уже даже не загружается а висит. Браузер в этот момент пишет "Ожидание свободного сокета". Нажатие на кнопки на других вкладках вообще не дает результатов.

Использую wildFly.

Почему так происходит и правильно ли я реализую COMET архитектуру?

Comment: COMET уже немного устарел. Лучше посмотрите в сторону веб-сокетов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно есть у браузеров ограничения на количество открытых XMLHttpRequest сокетов (5-10 в зависимости от браузера). Как подсказали в комментарии можно использовать WebSocket, который снимает это ограничение